# Load a layout from XML and add views

Tags: android, xml, layout, setcontentview

I'm trying to load an existing layout from XML and then create dynamically a button and a Circle, the reason which I cannot include them onto the XML is because the purpose is to create Circles dynamically, actually the following code is a snippet of what I want to create.

I know the way I am doing this (adding the layout) is wrong, but after reading a lot of Internet content I failed to did it by myself, because that I request help.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_etest);
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = this.getSystemService
    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)                             
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_etest ,
    null);
    LinearLayout viewGroup = layout;

    Button b1 = new Button(this); 
    b1.setText("test"); 
    viewGroup.addView(b1); 
    viewGroup.addView(new Circle(this));

    }

}
```

And my class Circle, which extends from View and its method onDraw() consists of:

```
  ... onDraw(){

  canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

   }
```

The parameters of drawCircle are not rellevant to this question. I have defined them elsewhere.

I also add the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why your content view layout and inflator layout is two different layout?

Comment: yes see my answer . instead of inflate it get it using id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one view group like `linearlayout` in your `xml` and using its `instance` add your dynamic views in that.

**activity_etest.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/viewg" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**activity**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_etest);
Linearlayout viewgroup = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewg);

 Button b1 = new Button(this); 
    b1.setText("test"); 
    viewGroup.addView(b1); 
    viewGroup.addView(new Circle(this));
```

Comment: How shoud I add the lines you provided in the xml? I tried it and the app crashes.

Comment: this is just a snippet can you please add your xml .

Comment: Ok, I add it to the first question.

Comment: now check . again  this is just an example. you can modify in your way